# Publish event in ibmiot cloud using json

Tags: c, json, ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I want to send accelerometer data to IBM iot cloud using  c language.

In this i am using json format to publish  event in cloud.

char *data="{\"d\" : {\"x\" : 43 }}"; //is working correctly ..

I want to send instant values through this pointer in JSON Format.. Please  help me how to send the instant values by using JSON format in IBMIOTfclient side

Answer (score 0):

If you use the IBMIOTfclient (iotfclient.h) you can call publishEvent, like:

`publishEvent(&client, "accel","json", "{\"d\" : {\"x\" : 43 }}", QOS0);`

There is a sample in [github](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-embeddedc/blob/master/samples/sampleDevice.c).

Comment: Thanks for your comment